# An uncommen complex Gaussian Integral with simple poles

Tags: integration, cauchy-integral-formula, gaussian-integral

I have problems with the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2+ibx^2}\left(\frac{1}{c/i+x}+\frac{1}{c/i-x}\right)dx,$$

where $a,b$ and $c$ are real numbers.

This screams Cauchy's integral formula to me, but i can't find a contour that works.

Note that if the pole is in the positive (negative) complex half-plane, the $i\sin$-part escapes in the negative (positive) complex half plane.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could use the Plancherel formula: the inner product of $f$ and $g$ is some constant multiple of the inner product of $\hat f$ and $\hat g$.  If $f$ is the Gaussian part, and $g$ the rational part, $\hat f$ is no worse looking than $f$, and $\hat g$ is something like $\exp(-d|t|)$, leading to an error-function like integral.

Comment: That worked! Thanks man